# Solution that starts in an invariant subspace stays in the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove that if $x(t)$ is a solution of the equation $x'=Ax$ where $A$ is a nxn matrix, and E is an invariant subspace, then if $x(t_{0})\in\ E$ for a certain $t_{0}$ then $x(t)\in\ E$ for all $t$. 
I tried to prove that $x'(t_{0})\in\ E$, $x''(t_{0})\in\ E$ and so forth and then using the taylor expansion of $x(t)$ centered at $t_{0}$. But I don't think this is a correct proof because I don't know if $x(t)$ is analytic and I cant guarantee that an infinte sum stays in $E$. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: This will work. $E$ is automatically closed. Are you familiar with the matrix exponential?

Comment: Thank you. Why is E closed? And how do I now x(t) is analytic? I've seen the definition for the matrix exponential and know that $e^(At)x$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not as succinct as the answer hinted to in Qiaochu's comment,
but can be extended to equations of the form $x' = f(x,t)$ with
appropriate Lipschitz and invariance assumptions on $f$.

Define $(Ly)(t) = x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t A y(\tau) d \tau$.

By applying the contraction mapping principle in a suitable manner
we can show that on any interval $[t_0, T]$, the iteration defined
by $x_0(t) = x(t_0)$, and $x_{n+1} = L x_n$ converges uniformly
to the solution of the differential equation $x' = Ax$ with initial
condition $x(t_0)$.

In particular, if $x$ is the solution, then $x(t) = \lim_n x_n(t)$.

Note that $E$ is closed since it is a (presumably) finite
dimensional subspace.

Note that if $y(t) \in E$ for all $t \ge t_0$ then $(Ly)(t) \in E$
for all $t \ge t_0$.

In particular, since $x_0(t) \in E $  for all $t\ge t_0$, we see that
$x_n(t) \in E$ for all $t \ge t_0$.

It follows that $x(t) \in E$ for all $t \ge t_0$.

**Aside**: I should show that if $\xi(t) \in E$ for all $t$ then
$\int_{t_0}^t \xi(t)(\tau) d \tau \in E$. Let $P$ be an orthogonal projection onto $E$, then $P (\int_{t_0}^t \xi(t)(\tau) d \tau) = \int_{t_0}^t P\xi(t)(\tau) d \tau = \int_{t_0}^t \xi(t)(\tau) d \tau$
and so $\int_{t_0}^t \xi(t)(\tau) d \tau \in E$.